# Trying to know the cut off point of an inbuilt function, since currently it is not running. In R

Tags: r

In R, I am trying to use the markov chain package and converting clickstream data to markov chain. I have 4GB of RAM but the program cannot run the command(after a lot of time). This is because after a while the ongoing conversion cannot allocate more than 3969mb of data(that is what the screen says). I am trying to find out that, as to what point will the program run? So if I have say `n' nodes, till how many nodes(obviously less than n) or rows(the rows might contain same or different nodes) will the program run. I am trying to do Attribution Modelling using R. The conversion path are converted from clickstream form to a markov chain. Trying to find out the transition matrix using that.

Image with the function and a sample dataset. Here the h,c,d,p are different nodes. [Image here of the code for a small clickstream data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6usF.png)

Attached the image of the code and a sample data. The function converts this data into a markov chain containing a lot of important things out of which I am mainly trying to get the Transition Matrix and the Steady State. As I increase the data size(the number of different channel path or Users are not important, it is the different nodes that are important), the function is unable to perform as it cannot allocate more than the 4GB of RAM. I tried hit and trial to get to the point beyond which the function is not working but it did not help. Is there a way where I can know that till what node(or row) will the function work? So that I can generate the Transition Matrix till that point. And maybe the increase in the memory usage with every increasing node as I would like to believe the relationship between the two won't be linear.

Please let me know if the question is not specific enough and if it might need any more details.

Comment: Please provide the code as text, not as an image. (Since what you provided is a direct copy from [`?clickstream::randomClicks`](http://search.r-project.org/library/clickstream/html/randomClicks-methods.html), it isn't that insightful. Are you doing anything else with the data or libraries?)

Comment: (BTW: the code worked in well under 0.1 seconds on my machine, and the memory use didn't bump any perceptible amount. What OS and version of R are you using?)

Comment: @r2evans It works very fast for a small number of nodes sir. But when you increase the nodes to say 1000, it becomes real slow. I am currently using Windows 8, 4GB RAM, 64 bit. The version of R that I am using is, R version 3.3.0

Comment: @r2evans : Sorry for the code issue. Should have provided the code. My bad sir. I have cleaned and converted my data in the clickstream form(the form that is there in the example I have attached) but the markov chain conversion is not taking place after the code runs for a long time as I get an error saying ; Cannot allocate more than 3969mb of space. I am sure the number of nodes that I am feeding in the form of clickstream data are more than it can handle. What I am trying to find out sir, is as to till what point will it be able to run?

Comment: Without any working example (nor any experience running this package), I'll be unable to provide any assistance. Good luck.